# change messages in ms teams chat

Tags: python, python-3.x, microsoft-teams

I am using the [library](https://pypi.org/project/pymsteams/)  to send messages to the chat.

```
import pymsteams
myTeamsMessage = pymsteams.connectorcard("<Microsoft Webhook URL>")
myTeamsMessage.title("Title")
myTeamsMessage.text("Text")
myTeamsMessage.send()
```

How can I access the sent message so that it can be changed over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using that library you can't update already sent messages, it uses Teams Webhooks and only sends messages.
Seems like you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/update-and-delete-bot-messages?tabs=dotnet

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this library does not support modifying your message but you can access what you sent by using `myTeamsMessage.payload["text"]`.